# StringFormatFlags and Serialization

Tags: c#, fonts, drawing, gdi+, string-formatting

I'm working on a graphics generation web service which takes a bunch of parameters for corresponding labels from a database and draws them onto an image. Is there any easy way for me to calculate the values for the [StringFormatFlags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.stringformatflags.aspx) enum. Ideally I'd like to use a single int field but I can't see a way to do that so far.

Comment: *Is there any easy way for me to calculate the values for the StringFormatFlags enum* What do you mean by this? You need to get value of enum? `Convert.ToInt32(enumvalue)`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can just cast the enum value into an int. For example,

```
foreach(var sff in Enum.GetValues(typeof(StringFormatFlags)))
{
   Debug.WriteLine((int)sff);
}
```

Comment: I know that, for example, I want to specify a line should be centered horizontally, at the top, with clipping. How would I serialize/deserialize this information without writing my own formatter?

Comment: You'll be serializing the integer value and deserializing will be `var position = ((StringFormatFlags)myInt)`. Not sure if there's anything built in but happy to be corrected.

Comment: I guess I was looking for a way of calculating those flag combinations without needing to step through the app.